# Adjusting Alignment in Math Mode

Tags: math-mode, align

I am using align to write my mathematical model in LaTeX, but the outcome looks like this: [image]

I do not understand why the for-all's are this far from the equation and the label is moved to the next line. My code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    \text{max} \qquad & w_1\left(\dfrac{\sum_{j \in I} d_j z_j - A_{min}} {A_{max}- A_{min}}\right) - w_2 \left(\dfrac{\sum_{p \in \mathcaL{P}} n_p- B_{min}}{B_{max}- B_{min}}\right) - \epsilon \sum_{p \in P} a_p \label{Eq1} \\
    \text{s.t.} \qquad  & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p \leq 1  & \forall j \in \mathcal{I}, \label{Eq2} \\
    &\sum_{\substack{i \in V_{1} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p - \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ji}} x_p  = 0 &  \forall i \in \mathcal{V}_1 \label{Eq3} \\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

I already checked the other questions related to this topic but I guess this is a different problem.

**Update**: I have tried the suggested answer on the equations I provided, but as I wrote longer equations it did not work:
[image]

The code is:

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[6em]
\begin{alignat}{3}
\max \qquad 
    & \mathrlap{w_1\Biggl(\frac{\sum_{j \in I} d_j z_j - A_{min}}{A_{\max}- A_{\min}}\Biggr) - 
                   \Biggl(\frac{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} n_p- B_{min}}{B_{\max}- B_{\min}}\Biggr) - \epsilon \sum_{p \in P} a_p}   \label{Eq1}     \\
\text{s.t.} \qquad  
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p \leq 1  \qquad & \forall j \in \mathcal{I},  \label{Eq2} \\
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{1} \\ i\neq j}} 
    \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p - \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} 
    \sum_{p \in P_{ji}} x_p = 0 \qquad &  \forall i \in \mathcal{V}_1 
    \label{Eq3} \\
    & y_p -  t_{o(p), \pi_{p(0)}}^{'}x_p = q_{p0} &  \forall p \in \mathcal{P}: \lvert \mathcaL{L} _p \rvert \neq 0 \label{Eq8} \\
    & Bx_p -  t_{\pi_{p(l-1)}, \pi_{p(l)}}^{'}x_p = q_{pl} &  \forall p \in \mathcal{P}: |\mathcaL{L}_{p}| \neq 0, \forall l \in \mathcaL{L}_p \textbackslash 0 
    \label{Eq9} \\
    & y_p - (t_p + s_{d(p)}) x_p + \sum_{l \in L_{p}} (Bx_p-q_{pl}) - t_{d(p), \alpha_{d(p)}}^{'} x_p \geq 0 & \forall p \in \mathcal{P} \label{Eq13} 
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please add to your code, starting with documentclass, everything that's needed to allow us to copy&run it. // Latex is powerful, so there are several way to deal with your problem ... which depends on your preamble (stuff after documentclass).

Comment: Unrelated but please don't use `\text`  like this, it does not do what you think.

Comment: Don't align the two `\forall ` replace the `&` in front by `\qquad`

Comment: You should take a look at the `optidef` package, which is dedicated to the layout of optimisation problems.

Comment: I added the package declarations in the beginning as well, thank you for the answers so far. When I replace & by \qquad the problem is fixed, but is this the correct way to write it in general?

Comment: Not mentioned in the answers, but the extra equation number (4) is caused by the presence of `\\ ` just before the end of the environment.  This should never be done; the result is an empty numbered (unless it's a starred environment) line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

(red lines indicate text area borders)

with use of `nccmath` and `mathtools` packages. Since I haven't your document class, I use `article` and increase \textwidht `by \geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{fleqn}[6em]
\begin{alignat}{3}
\max \qquad 
    & \mathrlap{w_1\Biggl(\frac{\sum_{j \in I} d_j z_j - A_{min}} 
                                {A_{\max}- A_{\min}}\Biggr) - 
                   \Biggl(\frac{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} n_p- B_{min}}
                                {B_{\max}- B_{\min}}\Biggr) - 
        \epsilon \sum_{p \in P} a_p}   \label{Eq1}     \\
\text{s.t.} \qquad  
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p \leq 1  
        \qquad & \forall j \in \mathcal{I},                \label{Eq2} \\
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{1} \\ i\neq j}} 
      \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p - \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} 
      \sum_{p \in P_{ji}} x_p = 0 
        \qquad &  \forall i \in \mathcal{V}_1 \label{Eq3} 
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
In your extended code you have two problems:

- condition in the penultimate row is to long
- last equation is to long

Combination of above force conditions to the right border of text, so they overwrite equations' numbers. Solution is to break condition penultimate row or break equation in the last row. Of course you can do both as is done in MQWE below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[6em]
\begin{alignat}{3}
\max \qquad
    & \mathrlap{w_1\Biggl(\frac{\sum_{j \in I} d_j z_j - A_{min}}
                                {A_{\max}- A_{\min}}\Biggr) -
                   \Biggl(\frac{\sum_{p \in \mathcal{P}} n_p- B_{min}}
                                {B_{\max}- B_{\min}}\Biggr) -
        \epsilon \sum_{p \in P} a_p}                        \label{Eq1} \\
\text{s.t.} \qquad
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}} \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p \leq 1
        \qquad & \forall j \in \mathcal{I},                \label{Eq2} \\
    & \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{1} \\ i\neq j}}
      \sum_{p \in P_{ij}} x_p - \sum_{\substack{i \in V_{0} \\ i\neq j}}
      \sum_{p \in P_{ji}} x_p = 0
        \qquad &  \forall i \in \mathcal{V}_1               \label{Eq3} \\
%   
    & y_p -  t_{o(p), \pi_{p(0)}}^{'} x_p = q_{p0} 
        \qquad &  \forall p \in \mathcal{P}: \abs{\mathcal{L}_p} \neq 0  \label{Eq8} \\
    & Bx_p -  t_{\pi_{p(l-1)}, \pi_{p(l)}}^{'}x_p = q_{pl}
        \qquad &    \begin{multlined}    
                \forall p \in \mathcal{P}: \abs{\mathcal{L}_{p}} \neq 0,\\
                \forall l \in \mathcal{L}_p = 0
                    \end{multlined}                         \label{Eq9} \\
    & \begin{multlined}
        y_p - (t_p + s_{d(p)}) x_p +    \\
        \sum_{l \in L_{p}} (Bx_p-q_{pl}) - t_{d(p), \alpha_{d(p)}}' x_p \geq 0
      \end{multlined}
        \qquad &  \forall p \in \mathcal{P}                 \label{Eq13} 
\end{alignat}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this but the for-all's did not fit the page this way.

Comment: @ecemm, apparently it works for me. If the first line of equations is on the page, than `\forall` fit on the page too. You use some not public documentclass. Does it produce two column document? Where it is available?

Comment: No it is a single-column document. It is a template for springer contributed books available at: https://www.springer.com/us/authors-editors/book-authors-editors/your-publication-journey/manuscript-preparation#c3324

Comment: @ecemm. OK, but fitrst line of my answer, does it fit on page? Can you show us )in question) what result you obtain with my code?

Comment: I'm sorry, your code did not work with me because I just put two sample constraints in here but I actually have more and one of them is creating an issue with this code piece. I have updated the question.

Comment: @ecemm, my code still work, but you increase length of equation so that they not fit on page anymore. See possible solution in addendum to my answer.